# Hyperlink - Go to next empty row?

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to create a 'go to next available row' button that will take my user to the next available row in my spreadsheet.

Here's what i'm using:

```
=HYPERLINK("#B" & MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(B:B),0,0),0),"First Empty")
```

VBA is out of the question as i don't have user privileges to edit vba code within this sheet.

The problem i have is, i have columns B - N in my spreadsheet.
Sometimes users will leave a cell blank and only fill in one column.

So the next available empty row in column B might be row 27 but column N's next empty row would be 51.

I need the formula to take all my columns into account when it takes the user to the next empty row for all my columns.

I also want to start the empty row search from row 3 onwards. Can this also be achieved?

please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of data and explain what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
=HYPERLINK("#B" & 1+SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(B1:N9999)*(B1:N9999<>"")))),"First Empty")
```

*(based on a suggestion from Scott Craner)*

Trim back the *9999* if you can, and extend it if you must.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will be able to do this in an easier way. I am curious. But the following formula would at least achieve it:

```
=HYPERLINK("#B"&1+LOOKUP(2,1/((B:B<>"")+(C:C<>"")+(D:D<>"")+(E:E<>"")+(F:F<>"")),ROW(A:A)),"First Empty")
```

This takes only columns `B` to `F`into account. But the principle should be clear and so you should be able expanding this up to column `N`.

This approach takes the row number of the last cell which has content in the columns and then adds 1. So it gets the first totally empty row.

Answer (score 0):

This could be modified to work for this purpose, but may not be easier than the other.

First, make sure the worksheet/tab you want to link to does not have spaces in the name. Underscores and Dashes will work though.

I changed the original described in the breakdown to count each column and then take the MAX()+1 to append to the link address. (*This wont take you to the very end properly if there are blanks in the longest row; but it would put you near the end of the row with the most data in it.)

**=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#Historical_Data!$A",SUM(MAX(COUNTA(Historical_Data!$A:$A),COUNTA(Historical_Data!$B:$B),COUNTA(Historical_Data!$C:$C)))+1),"Link to first Empty Row")**

Breakdown:
[=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(] = Sets up a way to dynamically specify the link address using Concatenate

["#Historical_Data!$A",] = "#" is required as the first character to identify that the link is in the same workbook. "Historical_Data" is the name of the tab/worksheet I linked to. "!$A" is the column ID I want the link to take me to.

[SUM(COUNTA(Historical_Data!$A$1:$A$366)-14)),] = Dynamically specifies the Row# that will be added to the end of the Link address above. I used the "SUM(COUTNA()-#" combination in this specific instance to make the last 14 rows of data show up when I click the link. You can put "+1" instead of "-14" to put the cursor on the first blank cell. The data range of "Historical_Data!$A$1:$A$366" was sufficient for me because my table will never have more than 365 days of data; works just as well with $A:$A as the range.

["Link to the xxxxxxx")] = Text that will display in the Hyperlinked Cell